# Anaconda disappears from my mac application folder

Tags: macos, anaconda

I was trying to install shogun in anaconda3, and it failed. Then I found that anaconda navigator icon disappeared in my launchpad as well as the application folder of my mac. I can still launch anaconda in terminal by "ancaconda-navigator", but I cannot do this by GUI. Is there any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me also. My efficient if not elegant solution was to simply create an **alias** to `/anaconda3/Anaconda-Navigator.app` in the **Applications** folder. This works and yields the same 'snakey-O' icon in the GUI.

[image]